# Inheriting Reference Type from ValueType

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

We know that in the framework, many valuetypes viz Int32, Double, etc. do inherit from reference types i.e Abstract class (System.ValueType and intern System.Object class). Now i was wondering if i could simulate similar concept explicitly via a C# code. Yes i absolutely know that C# compiler rules blocks it from being done. I do not know if VB.NET also blocks?

Below code sample just demonstrates much clearly.

```
    //Error code : Can not be done
    public abstract class MyClass
    {

    }

    public struct MyStruct : MyClass
    {
    }
```

So i though ill try to do the same via ilasm.exe, but it is giving weird error which i could not solve beside lots of googling. Any ways my question to you is, inside the framework it is possible to do this kind of inheritance but outside it can not be done.

Hence, is there some way i can simulate this scenario?

*P.S: Nope, i do not achieve any thing with respect to solving real world problem. Just will satisify my thoughts and learnings.*

Thanks & Happy Coding,

Zenwalker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ECMA 335 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)

Section I.8.9.10 (Value type inheritance):

> In their unboxed form value types do not inherit from any type. Boxed value types shall inherit
>   directly from `System.ValueType` unless they are enumerations, in which case, they shall inherit
>   from `System.Enum`. Boxed value types shall be sealed.
>
> Logically, the boxed type corresponding to a value type
>
> > Is an object type.
> >
> > Will specify which object type is its base type (i.e., the object type from which it inherits).
> >
> > Will have a base type that has no fields defined.
> >
> > Will be sealed to avoid dealing with the complications of value slicing.

The more restrictive rules specified here allow for more efficient implementation without severely compromising functionality.

It's therefore a limitation of the common type system, not of the C# language, that non-enum value types may inherit only from System.ValueType.

Comment: Boxing or unboxing happens at the run time. But i am looking more towards compile time itself.

Comment: @zenwalker in the context of the ECMA spec, unboxed value types do not inherit from anything, so a discussion of value type inheritance only has meaning for boxed value types.

Comment: Yes, but that happens at the run time right. Now if u open the framework IL, does it not show that it is inherting from reference types? Though may be its psuedo or it appears. But still i want to simulate some thing like that.

Comment: @zenwalker Right, the bit about inheritance applying only to boxed values is a bit of a distraction.  However, the point is that Common Type System specifies that value types *must inherit directly from ValueType or Enum*, which means that there's no way to create a value type that inherits directly from any other reference type.  You could perhaps "simulate", to some degree, by making an immutable reference type, because these behave like value types in some ways.  But ultimately, they're reference types, so the answer to your question is "no."